# How to use function only once with onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm very new with javascript and been trying to make a function code that only work only once.

this is my logo that i've been trying to animate it.

```
<img src="img/logot2.png" id="logoutjs" onmouseover="move()" alt="Logo" width="100" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" style="position: absolute; right: 8px;" >
```

and this is the javascript.

```
<script>
  var id = null;
  function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("logoutjs");   
    var pos = 0;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
      if (pos == -110) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        pos--;
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
      }
    }
    move(){};
  }
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onmouseover` attribute from image

```html
<img src="img/logot2.png" id="logoutjs" alt="Logo" width="100" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" style="position: absolute; right: 8px;" >
```

Then use `addEventListener` with `{once: true}`

```js
let img = document.querySelector("#logoutjs");
img.addEventListener("mouseover", move, {once: true})

var id = null;

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("logoutjs");
  var pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == -110) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--;
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For me this yields an error `"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"`

Comment: thank you i replaced my old code with this new one. And it worked!!! i still have much to learn

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes that would make sense as it would go into infinite recursion with no exit condition.

Comment: @YovanDwinandaH Please remove `move()` function call from the end. Check the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one problem is the function call at the bottom of the function definition? I would suggest omitting the `move() {}`

One other thing is that you don't have to use the `document.getElementById`. You should be able to access the image by adding event as a parameter in your function and using event.target.

If you want the function to work only once and then never again, remove the eventhandler at the bottom of the function.

```
<img src="img/logot2.png" id="logoutjs" onmouseover="move(event)" alt="Logo" width="100" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" style="position: absolute; right: 8px;" >
<script>
  var id = null;
  function move(event) {   
    var pos = 0;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
      if (pos == -110) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        pos--;
        event.target.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
      }
    }
    event.target.removeAttribute("onmouseover");
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, it also works in my code